# Trying to take a picture and then store it + have access to it

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera

So, I have an app where I want to take a picture, store it to internal storage, and then be able to retrieve it later (presumably via its Uri). Here is what I have thus far:
This code is triggered when my custom camera button is pressed.

```
cameraButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final Intent takePic = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            File file = herp(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
            if (file != null) {
                fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(file);
                Log.d("AddRecipeActivity", fileUri.toString());
                takePic.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
                startActivityForResult(takePic, CAMERA_REQUEST);
            }
        }
    });
```

Next, I've defined two methods later on in the code(mostly taken from the android developer site):

```
 /** Create a file Uri for saving an image or video */
private static Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(File file){
    return Uri.fromFile(file);
}

/** Create a File for saving an image or video */
public File herp(int type){
    // To be safe, you should check that the SDCard is mounted
    // using Environment.getExternalStorageState() before doing this.
    Boolean a = false;
    String externalDirectory= getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
    File folder= new File(externalDirectory + "/NewFolder");


    // This location works best if you want the created images to be shared
    // between applications and persist after your app has been uninstalled.

    // Create the storage directory if it does not exist


    if (!folder.exists()){
        a = folder.mkdirs();
        Log.d("AddRecipeActivity", String.valueOf(a));
        }




    // Create a media file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    File mediaFile;
    if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE){
        mediaFile = new File(folder.getPath() + File.separator +
                "IMG_"+ timeStamp + ".jpg");
    }  else {
        return null;
    }
    if(mediaFile == null){
        Log.d("AddRecipeActivity", "Media file is null");
    }
    return mediaFile;
}
```

When I print my Uri (right before triggering the intent) I get the following output.

```
04-04 04:22:40.757 22402-22402/scissorkick.com.project2 D/AddRecipeActivity: file:///data/user/0/scissorkick.com.project2/files/NewFolder/IMG_20160404_042240.jpg
```

Also, when I check if the directory is made, the boolean is true.
When my camera intent's onActivityResult is run, however, the result code is 0.

Why might it fail at this point? I've defined the appropriate permissions in the manifest, and also request external storage write permissions during run time.

Edit: Added the onActivityResult:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    if(requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST){
        Log.d("AddRecipe", String.valueOf(resultCode));
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            thumb = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(photo, 240, 240);
            photoView.setImageBitmap(thumb);
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "image saved to:\n" + data.getData(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

There's some nonsense code in the onActivityResult, but the point is that the resultCode = 0 and I don't know why.

Comment: show your onActivityResult codes

Comment: Added. I think it's wired up properly, but I'm not 100%

Comment: Did you solved your problem??

Answer (score 0):

In your final activity, put the below code

```
    data.putExtra("uri", uri);//uri = your image uri
    getActivity().setResult(""result_code", data);
    getActivity().finish();
```

Then in your onActivityResult code you can get the uri like

```
Uri uri = data.getExtras().getParcelable("uri");
```

Then you can use this Uri value to retrieve your image.

Answer (score 0):

There is how i take picture in my app!

When i press my own Image Button

```
static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;
static final int REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO = 1
static final String STATE_PHOTO_PATH = "photoPath";

ImageButton photoButton = (ImageButton) this.findViewById(R.id.take_picture_button);
        photoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dispatchTakePictureIntent();
            }
        });
```

And here how manage and create/store the file with image

```
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
        );

        // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
        mCurrentPhotoPath = "file:" + image.getAbsolutePath();
        return image;
    }

    //Create a new empty file for the photo, and with intent call the camera
    private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            // Create the File where the photo should go
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // Error occurred while creating the File
                Log.e("Error creating File", String.valueOf(e.getMessage()));
            }
            // Continue only if the File was successfully created
            if (photoFile != null) {
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                        Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                //I have the file so now call the Camera
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
            }
        }
    }

    private void openImageReader(String imagePath) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        Uri imgUri = Uri.parse(imagePath);
        intent.setDataAndType(imgUri, "image/*");
        startActivity(intent);

    }
```

In the ActivityResult i only save a record in DB, with the Path of the image so i can retrieve it back and read the photo stored like file.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            //Save the path of image in the DB
            db.addCompito(new Compiti(activity_name, null, mCurrentPhotoPath));
            refreshListView();
        }
    }
```

If you have some screen rotation don't forget to add something like

```
@Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Save the user's current game state
        savedInstanceState.putString(STATE_PHOTO_PATH, mCurrentPhotoPath);

        // Always call the superclass so it can save the view hierarchy state
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }


    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Always call the superclass so it can restore the view hierarchy
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

        // Restore state members from saved instance
        mCurrentPhotoPath = savedInstanceState.getString(STATE_PHOTO_PATH);
    }
```

**WHY?**

Because when the rotation change you can lose the file that you have created for the "new photo" and when you accept it and save it, your photopath is null and no image is created.